# Problem with Getting object from class of back4app database FLUTTER ONLY

Tags: flutter, parse-platform, back4app

I'm getting dumb with this

```
Future Object1() async{
final object1 = await ParseObject('Announcement')..objectId='vG1WZeVHkV';
var mal = await object1.get('an1');
await print(mal);
```

}

just in case you ask the result for that

```
I/flutter ( 9123): null
```

when I was hoping for this url (it is a file column in back4app for image)

```
"an1":{"__type":"File","name":"6c128c064142552b8c3a5e2ac016bc1d_1.jpg","url":"https://parsefiles.back4app.com/nQ1FGO9uklC7f9eMKYDuA16pvAjamCYnbI6xD2Zy/6c128c064142552b8c3a5e2ac016bc1d_1.jpg"}
```

(note I got this from using object1.fetch() )

so can anyone help me???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```dart
Future Object1() async {
  final object1Response = await ParseObject('Announcement').getObject('vG1WZeVHkV');
  if (object1Response.success) {
    final object1 = object1Response.result;
    var mal = await object1.get('an1');
    print(mal);
  }
}
```

Comment: hey man.thx.. never thought I should use get object id first.. thx pal